# Using System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a WPF application and I use external library for generating documents. This library returns document as System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument. How can I print this document in WPF? I can use Print() method directly, but I need to allow user to select printer and settings. If I use WPF PrintDocument dialog, I can't set my document to it as in WinForms dialog.Document. Is there a way to convert old PrintDocument to some WPF friendly form?

WinForms way:

```
// get document for printing
PrintDocument document = exporter.GetPrintDocument();
System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
dialog.Document = document;
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    document.Print();
}
```

WPF way:

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    // how to print old PrintDocument???
    dialog.PrintDocument(...);
}
```

I also tried to open WinForms dialog in WPF but it is not possible. Dialog is just not shown.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. You have to set `UseDialogEx` dialog property to `true`.

Comment: This person is referring to using a WinForms PrintDialog and setting the UseDialogEx so that it will work in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

```
MessageBox.Show(printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);
printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "A.txt"; 
MessageBox.Show(printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName);   

printDialog1.ShowDialog();
printDocument1.DocumentName = "A.txt";
if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```